# Is the usage of "in" in the following sentence correct?

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions

Is the usage of *in* in the following sentence correct?

> She sacrificed her own life in to teach my father a lesson and hoped to keep us alive.

I am reading a book that one of my friends wrote; she asked me to read it & see if there is anything that needs to be edited.

Although I am not the person to do this job, but I am doing my best to fulfill this wish for her.

Comment: Hello Nada. Reading texts to correct grammar etc is specifically off-topic on this website. However: 'She sacrificed her own life in order to teach my father a lesson and hoped to keep us alive.' is grammatical. But it runs together two different trains of thought that really need setting apart.

Comment: "sacrificed her own life **in teaching** my father a lesson" or maybe even "sacrificed her own life **to teaching** my father a lesson" if I understand correctly what is meant in the sentence.

Comment: The complete sentence could be _In the hope it would keep us alive, she sacrificed her own life in order to teach my father a lesson ._ but is too long

Comment: @mplungjan I think you have hit the nail perfectly on the head. But I don't see why such a sentence would be 'too long'.

Comment: Edwin Ashworth, thank you for your help, and for informing me about the rule. I also appreciate the participation of "mplungjan & WS2.

Answer (score 2):

No, it should either say **in order to**, or just **to**.

Answer (score 0):

Converting comment to answer

As said by Reg, the "in to" should be "to" or "in order to"

Reversing some of the sentence makes it flow better.

> In the hope it would keep us alive, she sacrificed her own life in order to teach my father a lesson

It does duplicate the "in" and puts the sacrifice secondary so perhaps

> She sacrificed her own life in the hope it would keep us alive by teaching my father a lesson.